# How I can use Java Reflection API within EJB 3 entity?

Tags: reflection, jboss, ejb-3.0, stateless-session-bean

I do the following steps with eclipse 3.5 ,JBoss 4.2 ,EJB3 but I face class not found exception

1.compiling this code to foo.jar file

```
package mypackage.foo;
import myejbpackage.ejb.fooInterface; 
class foo implements fooInterface{
 @override
 void helloWorld(){System.out.print("HelloWorld");}
     }
```

Note that fooInterface  interface in is written inside the used EJB

2.using reflection , I take an instance from this class, also with the same ejb

```
package myejbpackage.ejb;
class fooCaller{
    void call(){
     Class foo=  Class.forName("mypackage.foo.foo");
```

fooInterface iDataBackupWriter  =(fooInterface) foo.newInstance();
   fooInterface.helloWorld();
           }
    }

3.then calling it within stateless ejb3

```
package myejbpackage.ejb;
test(){        
  System.Out.Write("before calling");
   new fooCaller().call();
    }
```

4.then deploying to Jboss 4.2 and  and puting foo.jar in default/lib

5.then calling the ejb 3 method.using simple client

it print :

```
 "before calling"
```

and the following exception occurs in eclipse console

```
  javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:                       myejbpackage/ejb/fooInterface; nested exception is: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myejbpackage/ejb/fooInterface
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:myejbpackage/ejb/fooInterface
```

Any suggestion ?
1.Is this exception from JBOOS, why ?
1.Where I should put the foo.jar to bee seen with the ejb3 jar ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a circular dependency which generate this problem